# How do I resolve this wildcard capture issue when using java generics?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am having issues using java generics - specifically, using wildcard capture. Here is a simplified version of the code I have that exhibits the problem I am seeing. It is driving me crazy:

```
public class Task {

    private Action<ActionResult, ? extends ActionSubject> action;
    private ActionSubject subject = new ActionSubjectImpl();

    private List<ActionResult> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setAction(new ActionImpl());
        task.doAction();
    }

    public void setAction(Action<ActionResult, ? extends ActionSubject> action) {
    this.action = action;
    }

    public void doAction() {
        list.add(action.act(subject));
    }      

    public static class ActionResult { }

    public interface Action<T, U> {
        public T act(U argument);
    }    

    public interface ActionSubject {
        public String getName();
    }

    public static class ActionImpl implements Action<ActionResult, ActionSubjectImpl>{
        @Override
        public ActionResult act(ActionSubjectImpl argument) {
            // Code that requires ActionSubjectImpl specifically instead of the interface.
            // This classes implmentation of action should only support ActionSubjectImpl as an
            // argument.
            return new ActionResult();
        }
    }

    public class ActionSubjectImpl implements ActionSubject {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "I am a subject";
        }
    }
}
```

Package declaration and imports are not included - otherwise this is complete. This does not compile. The problem is with the fragment `list.add(action.act(subject));` where I am seeing the error message :

```
incompatible types: ActionSubject cannot be converted to CAP#1
 where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
  CAP#1 extends ActionSubject from ? extends ActionSubject
```

I can see from other posts that helper methods are suggested as a way get things like this to work, but I have not been able to come up with one that works.

The `Action action` has the type parameters like so: `Action<ActionResult, ? extends ActionSubject>` and the `ActionSubject` that I am passing in to the `act` method is of interface type 'ActionSubject' and of concrete type 'ActionSubjectImpl' although the code fragment in question will not see the concrete type of course. The second type parameter of `Action` should support any type that extends `ActionSubject` - and it is fine when I set `action` to `new ActionImpl()`, where the second type is `ActionSubjectImpl`.

I would appreciate any comment on what I am doing wrong here in my definitions and use of generics. I may be missing something basic here. I could code this a different way, but until I understand what is going wrong I won't be able to move on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is your misunderstanding: You said:

> The second type parameter of `Action` should support any type that extends `ActionSubject`

This is not correct. The second type parameter of `Action` is constrained to be a specific subclass of `ActionSubject`, e.g., `MyActionSubject`. So you can't pass in an arbitrary `ActionSubject` instance, because that's a more generic type.

If you want to have arbitrary subtypes of `ActionSubject`, just use `ActionSubject` as the second type parameter instead of `? extends ActionSubject`.

Comment: Hi. If I do that `task.setAction(new ActionImpl());` fails with `ActionImpl cannot be converted to Action<ActionResult,ActionSubject>` since my `ActionImpl` implements `Action<ActionResult,ActionSubjectImpl>`

Comment: Maybe you want the field to be `private Action<ActionResult, ActionSubjectImpl> action;`?

Or use `Task<T extends ActionSubject>` and make it `private Action<ActionResult, T> action;`?

Comment: I won't know at compile time (within Task) which `Action` implementation and hence which `ActionSubject` implementation will be used, so the first option is a no go - I only included `ActionSubjectImpl` embedded here to demonstrate. But the second option is interesting - and it works for my code example. I will test it with my real code and if that is fine I will mark this as answered. Thanks!